# How to tell the default values of optional arguments for MATLAB Built in functions?

Tags: matlab, parameters, built-in, default-arguments

Is there a way to tell the default values of optional arguments in MATLAB?

For example, the function [quadprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) will run as **`quadprog(H, f)`** and **`quadprog(H,f,A,b)`**.

Is there a way to tell the default values of **`A`** and **`b`** if I execute `quadprog(H, f)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't provide `A` and `b`, MATLAB assumes that you are solving an *unconstrained* quadratic optimization problem. So, they are empty. This is a common trait of optimization solvers; if you don't provide constraints, it will assume that the problem is unconstrained.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want to know the default value so that you can supply a later optional argument, forcing you to provide something for all the ones in front, but get the same behavior as if they were left out.

Most MATLAB functions treat an empty matrix (`[]`) the same as a missing argument.  So you can for example, say

```
quadprog(H, F, [], [], Aeq, Beq)
```

if you have no inequality constraints.

Comment: I'm actually working on implementing some given code (which calls Matlab's quadprog) in another language (C++). The C++ library I'm using appears to require A be specified, so I was hoping to use whatever matlab's default is. It sounds like my idea was over simplifying the problem.

Comment: @Anne: Well, try passing an empty matrix through the C++ wrapper.